# Shared Preference not working across two activities?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**Writing preference from file Login.java:**

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();
```

**Loading preference in UpdateList.java:**

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UpdateList.this);
           String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");
```

I want to pass this shared preference to a php file through json, but it is not able to save the preference across two activities

Comment: pass the application context instead Login.this or UpdateList.this: `.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: Have already tried this. Still not working

Comment: when assigning the variable username, are you sure it is not null?

Comment: Do you have any `android:process` attributes in your manifest for either of these `<activity>` elements?

Comment: @xabier yes I am sure the username is not null. that username in fact is provided by the user during login, without which, the app doesn't proceed to the next activity

Comment: @CommonsWare nope. I don't have any process attribute for any of those activities

Comment: You might want to run this on an emulator and take a look at the actual preference values in their XML file (`/data/data/whatever.your.app.package.is/shared_prefs/`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to access and write your SharePreference

```
public static final String PREF_FIELD = "name";
    public String getText(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                    "GLOBAL",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String sessionId = preferences.getString(
                    PREF_FIELD,
                    "");
            return sessionId;
        }

        public void setText(Context context, String text) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                    "GLOBAL",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_FIELD, text);
            editor.commit();
        }
```